# Printing a specific chosen line of a string ; Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ok so, let's say I have a string that looks something like this.

```
str = """
     abcedjhg
     by234aaD
     Xucu2345
     Cmn23481         
     vj3h4123
     """
```

I would like to be able to select a single line from that string and print it out

Usage e.g

```
>> input("What line would you like to view? \n : ")
>> What line would you like to view? 
>>  : 3
>> Xucu2345
```

Im not too sure how to actually select the line and store it as a str for it to be printed.

I'd appreciate your help! As usual, if you would like me to explain it better just ask. I'm not sure what exactly to ask w/ a question like this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you using `str.split("\n")` method to build a list including each line of the string, and also `str.strip()` to remove the leading whitespaces.
And please do not use the `str` as the variable name, because it is also the name of string type in Python. It could lead to mistakes.
Here is my solution:

```
s  = """
     abcedjhg
     by234aaD
     Xucu2345
     Cmn23481         
     vj3h4123
     """

lines = [line.strip() for line in s.split("\n")]
line_nb = input("What line would you like to view? \n : ")

print(lines[int(line_nb)])

# What line would you like to view? 
# : 3
#Xucu2345
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `split` to split str  and print the desired string

```
list=str.split("\n")
print(list[3].strip())
```

`strip` will truncate the leading and succeeding white spaces